# How to search for the next keyword in a line of data

Tags: python, iteration

I'm trying to iterate through `datafile` and search for a keyword in the data. If that keyword is found, I want to print the third word in the next line. Example:

```
for line in data:
    nextline = next(data)
    if 'REMARK 350 BIOMOLECULE:' == line.strip():
        bio = nextline[2]    
    print("\t".join([bio]), file=datafile)  
datafile.close()
```

Here, I'm searching for the words 'REMARK 350 BIOMOLECULE:', and if found, print out the third column of the next line : "AUTHOR" as output

Comment: How do you get `data`? Can you paste your full code?

Comment: If you do `nextline = next(data)`, you're going to skip that next line, as `next` counts as a iteration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: removed extra `:` on `catch`

You need a flag.

```
catch = False
for line in data:
    if catch:
        magic = line.split()[2]
        print(f"\t{magic}", file=datafile)  
    catch = 'REMARK 350 BIOMOLECULE:' == line.strip()
datafile.close()
```

Turned into an complete script:

```
import sys
datafile = sys.stdout
data = """\
REMARK 350 BIOMOLECULE:
REMARK 350 AUTHOR""".splitlines()
catch = False
for line in data:
    if catch:
        magic = line.split()[2]
        print(f"\t{magic}", file=datafile)  
    catch = 'REMARK 350 BIOMOLECULE:' == line.strip()
datafile.close()
```

Output:

```
C:\tmp>python x.py
        AUTHOR
C:\tmp>
```

Comment: It says invalid syntax for the second to last line

Comment: Yes, and even a Python beginner should be able to delete the colon that I accidentally added.

Comment: bool object is not callable if catch:

Comment: Nowhere in that code do I use `catch` as a callable.